# How do I proof that $<(EF, ND) \leq CDN$?

Tags: geometry

[image]

And what is $<(EF, ND)$ also equal to?

Comment: Does $<(EF,ND)$ denote the angle obtained by projecting these two (non-intersecting!) lines to a plane parallel to both? In that case, note that $EF\|DC$.

Comment: 1. Perhaps.. 2. Does EF||DC mean that they are parallel to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your notation means what Hagen von Eitzen pointed out.

Since $EF\parallel MN,$ you'll find 
$$<(EF, ND)=\angle MND=\angle CDN.$$

Also, you'll find 
$$\begin{align}<(EF, ND)&\leq(HG, ND)\\&\leq(DC, ND)\\& \leq(AB, ND)\\& \leq(FE,MC)\\&\leq(GH,MC)\\& \leq(CD, MC)\\&\leq(BA, MC).\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you proof that (EF, ND) is the same as angle (MND)?

Comment: Because $EF||MN$.

Comment: @GreerPers: Does this help? If not, why not ask?